# is there a way to write in cells vertically via xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to organize the (split)ed result vertically like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFlcd.png)

not this

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
ws = wb.sheets.active
result = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
ws.range(1,1).value = result.split(",")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [xlwings tutorial](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists) says:

> To write a list in column orientation to Excel, use `transpose`:
>
> ```
> sht.range('A1').options(transpose=True).value = [1,2,3,4]
> ```